# border-radius only works on one side of the div

Tags: html, css, border, border-radius

I was trying to apply `border-radius` on a div, and I notice that `border-radius` will only work on one side if this side's radius value gets too big like below. How exactly can I solve this while keeping the `border-radius` value on both sides?

```css
.wrapper1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 999px 2px 2px 999px;
}
.wrapper2{
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="wrapper2">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: 999px is just too much. Use a value that makes more sense. `border-radius: 75px 2px 2px 75px;`

Comment: border radius works fine, it's the values you give it that are aberrant

Comment: why is the border radius value on the left side affecting the other side? Shouldn't they only affect the relative corner?

Comment: border-radius is more complex than what you think. Each value has an impact on its corner and adjacent corners as well

Answer (score 0):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds/#corner-overlap):

> Corner curves must not overlap: When the sum of any two adjacent border radii exceeds the size of the border box, UAs **must proportionally reduce** the used values of all border radii until none of them overlap.

So yes, a border-radius on one corner affect adjacent corners. If you want to have accurate detail, check the specification to find all the formula and geometry behind border-radius

Here is a more trivial example:

```css
.wrapper1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 9999px 100px 100px 9999px;
}
.wrapper2{
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="wrapper2">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Swap the values from PX to EM and it should work as intended:

```
border-radius: 9em 0.2em 0.2em 9em;
```